# SQL LEFT JOIN without duplicating same row values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I was wondering if someone can help me with my problem that is as follows:
I want to pull once posts.text and uids which belongs to that posts.text but when I execute the code below it does this: eg. there are 4 uids that belongs to the post so I get the posts.text four times instead of once.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,
                  "SELECT posts.text, relationships.uidb
                  FROM posts
                  LEFT JOIN relationships
                  ON posts.uid=relationships.uida
                  LIMIT 10");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['text']." ".$row['uidb']."<br>";
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks is advance.
Peter

Update:
Desired output would be like this:

```
postsArray[0]->text = //post text
postsArray[1]->text = //another post text
postsArray[0]->uids[0] = //approved uid for first post
postsArray[0]->uids[1] = //another approved uid for first post
```

now it outputs this:
text 10
text 15
text 12

and I want this:
text 10, 15, 12

Comment: But there are 4 relationships... which do you want? If you want to load the text separately then that'd work, otherwise this is a relational database and it's giving you back what you asked for. Or, if you don't want this back can you provide some sample input data and the desired output?

Comment: So do you only want 1 `uidb` per `text` (and which 1) or do you want all `uidb` per `text`?

Comment: I want all uidb and one text

Comment: @peterpetr4 How many uids a post can have, maximum amount of uids on post just asking

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid post can have unlimited uids, maybe I just don't know how to correctly access the output, because i want to get output like this:

postsArray[0].text = post text
postsArray[0].uids[1] = uid number
postsArray[0].uids[2] = another uid number

Comment: @peterpetr4 can you share your expected output format by editing your question

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use Mysql's `GROUP_CONCAT` which provides comma separated values list for each group i.e (p.uid)

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT p.text, GROUP_CONCAT(r.uidb SEPARATOR ', ') uidbs
     FROM posts p
     LEFT JOIN relationships r
     ON p.uid=r.uida
     GROUP BY p.uid
     LIMIT 10");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['text'].' '.$row['uidbs'];
      /*$uidbs=  explode($row['uidbs'],',');
        foreach ($uidbs as $key => $val) {
            echo $val.' ';
        }*/
        echo '</br>';
    }
}
```

---

- [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> According to docs The result is truncated to the maximum length that
>   is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a
>   default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the
>   effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the
>   value of max_allowed_packet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might work for you:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,
                  "SELECT posts.text, relationships.uidb
                  FROM posts
                  LEFT JOIN relationships
                  ON posts.uid=relationships.uida
                  GROUP BY posts.uid
                  LIMIT 10");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['text']." ".$row['uidb']."<br>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.text, relationships.uidb
              FROM posts
              LEFT JOIN relationships
              ON posts.uid=relationships.uida
              GROUP BY posts.primary_key_of_your_post
             LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call 2 queries. In your first query, call the text, and then call uids.

You should not write complex queries because this will make your business more complex and you will not maintain your code in future.